# Remove encoding artefacts from MP3?

Tags: osx, audio, mp3

I have some old mp3's that I wanted to listen to, but I discovered that there are some annoying "pops" and "glitches" in them at some places.

I remember back in the day (20 years ago) when one would download mp3's on a 56.6kbps modem (one song would take 15 minutes to download!) the result would often have some similar but more pronounced artefacts. The tool to remove them were some Windows command line tools named `uncook` and `detox`.

So I probably need something like that - but for Mac OSx. Just a simple Terminal app or script would be preferable, or one that isn't bloated but still supports batch processing.

What are some good (preferably free) tools for this kind of thing on OSx?

Comment: maybe an interesting thread: https://hydrogenaud.io/index.php/topic,92704.0.html

Comment: Click removal, noise reduction, or repairing are the terms I believe you are thinking of.